# Error handling in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I just started using Kivy and was wondering how I am supposed to handle exceptions. For example, in a simple Python script that runs in the command line, I would normally `print` the error first then use `sys.exit(1)` to exit the script. However, I noticed `sys.exit(1)` causes my Kivy application to completely close.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to handle errors, you should look at the [ExceptionHandler](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.base.html?highlight=exceptionhandler#kivy.base.ExceptionHandler) class.

After following the discussion on the [Kivy GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1572) page, it seems the most graceful way to handle errors is to just handle errors with Python as you normally would, but you *could* use the `ExceptionHandler` class.